# How to display usernames in Woocommerce Admin orders list custom column?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to make a custom Woocommerce order overview column which displays the WordPress user.

This is the code which resides in the `functions.php` file:

```
// ADDING A NEW COLUMN
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'k2i_extra_column_eldest_players', 20 );
function k2i_extra_column_eldest_players($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    // Inserting columns to a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            // Inserting after "Status" column
            $reordered_columns['skb-client'] = __( 'Oudste Speler','theme_domain');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding custom fields meta data for the column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
    switch ( $column )
    {
        case 'skb-client' :
            // Get custom post meta data
            $my_var_one = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_name', true );
            if(!empty($my_var_one))
                echo $my_var_one;

            // Testing (to be removed) - Empty value case
            else
                echo '<small>(<em>no value</em>)</small>';

            break;
    }
}
```

I think my mistake is in this line of code:

```
$my_var_one = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'user_name', true );
```

The meta key `'user_name'` probably isn't the right one... But I can't seem to find the right one.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** The right `meta_key` to get the **user ID** in woocommerce orders is `_customer_user`, so:

```
$user_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_customer_user', true );
```

Or you can use `$the_order` global object as:

```
global $the_order;
$user_id = $the_order->get_customer_id();
```

After you can get the WordPress userdata from this user ID:

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $userid );

echo 'Username: ' . $user_data->user_login . "<br>";
echo 'User email: ' . $user_data->user_email . "<br>";
echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_data->roles) . "<br>";
echo 'User ID: ' . $user_data->ID . "<br>";
echo 'User full name: ' . $user_data->last_name .  ", " . $user_data->first_name . "<br>";
```

So in your code:

```
// Adding a custom new column to admin orders list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_column_eldest_players', 20 );
function custom_column_eldest_players($columns)
{
    $reordered_columns = array();

    // Inserting columns to a specific location
    foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
        $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
        if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
            // Inserting after "Status" column
            $reordered_columns['skb-client'] = __( 'Oudste Speler','theme_domain');
        }
    }
    return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding custom fields meta data for the column
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
    if ( 'skb-client' != $column ) return;

    global $the_order;

    // Get the customer id
    $user_id = $the_order->get_customer_id();

    if( ! empty($user_id) && $user_id != 0) {
        $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
        echo $user_data->user_login; // The WordPress user name
    }
    // Testing (to be removed) - Empty value case
    else
        echo '<small>(<em>Guest</em>)</small>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

[image]

Comment: Hello LoicTheAztec, thanks for your very detailed example. I've made the changes to my code, but it seems that the column values are empty now. Before when I was using wrong meta keys I got _(no value)_, now I'm getting an empty column, so I guess something is happening, but that the data can't be retrieved.

I'll add a screenshot for clarification: [click here!](https://i.gyazo.com/1ba9d82e06e41383a253890845165958.png)

Comment: @ArneDeBelser I need to test it… I will come back to you very soon…

Comment: No problem! I am also searching, maybe I can find it before you do! :P (Thanks btw)

Comment: @ArneDeBelser Found the problem, Updated and working… :)

Comment: Thanks, it indeed works! I accept this answer.

What exactly did you do to fix the problem, as far as I can tell you took out the switch statement (which wasn't really needed in there).

You've also made a check that skb-client indeed is a column.
But I don't really see any differences in the if statement where you echo out the user_login.

Comment: @ArneDeBelser It was a very very stupid hidden mistake in a variable name `get_userdata( $userid );` instead of  `get_userdata( $user_id );` … and I have maid some other minor changes…